# 100s of "Extracting BindingMaps" messages on Azure deployment of postsharp 3 project

Tags: postsharp

I'm deploying from TeamCity into Azure (the [TeamMentor/Dev](http://Github.com/TeamMentor/Dev) project) and am getting a large number of messages like this on the azure deployment logs.

Any ideas why?

```
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Processing archive: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\tm-dinis\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Web Applications\packages\PostSharp.3.0.31\tools\PostSharp-Tools.exe [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:    [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\.NETCore,v4.5\.NETPortable,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\.NETFramework,v4.0\.NETPortable,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\.NETFramework,v4.5\.NETPortable,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\.NETPortable,v4.5\.NETPortable,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\Silverlight,v4.0\.NETPortable,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\Silverlight,v5.0\.NETPortable,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\WindowsPhone,v8.0\.NETPortable,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\.NETFramework,v4.5\.NETPortable,v4.5.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\.NETFramework,v4.0\Silverlight,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\.NETFramework,v4.5\Silverlight,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\Silverlight,v5.0\Silverlight,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\WindowsPhone,v8.0\Silverlight,v4.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  BindingMaps\WindowsPhone,v8.0\Silverlight,v5.0.AssemblyMap [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x64-cil.exe.config [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x64.exe.config [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x86-cil.exe.config [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x86.exe.config [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  bin.Release\PostSharp.HQ.v3.0.exe.config [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  bin.Release\PostSharp.Licensing.exe.config [K
[12:31:44][Step 2/3] remote:   Extracting  bin.Release\postsharp.srv.4.0-x64.exe.config [K
```

I only started seeing this after I updated to PostSharp v3 (from v2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostSharp needs to self-extract itself upon first execution (otherwise you would have these 100s of files in source control, which you surely don't want) and these are the messages emitted by the SFX. You see them because your build server collects messages with high verbosity.

Comment: Yeah, but they happen on most (if not all) pushes to Azure, can't they be cached somewhere?
Also since not all are needed, can't just some be extracted (note that it does have significant performance impact to do that extraction on push)

Comment: It is cached in C:\ProgramData, but perhaps Azure keeps removing it.

Comment: Most likely, so is there a way to indicate another location to extract it?

Comment: See `PostSharp.tasks` lines 62 to 70.